# Was versteht man unter einem "maßlosen Sinn"?

Tags: word-usage, usage, idiom, meaning

Ich habe bei [dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=sinn) gerade (sinnfrei) nach den englischen Übersetzungen für *Sinn* gesucht und bin dabei auf etwas gestoßen, das ich erst nur komisch zu lesen fand. Und beim Sinnen über den Sinn bzw. die Bedeutung dessen, was ich las, empfand ich diese Begrifflichkeit irgendwie unangenehm:

> maßloser Sinn

Was bitte soll das bedeuten?

- übertriebene Sinnhaftigkeit (einer Aussage / Tätigkeit) -> Da bliebe mir der Sinn davon verborgen.
- veralteter Ausdruck für die übermenschlichen Fähigkeiten von Superhelden
- oder etwa, dass man Sinn und Zweck nicht messen kann?

Ist die kurze Nacht oder die zu hohe Dosis Koffein während des Tages daran schuld, oder fehlt mir einfach die nötige Vorstellungskraft?

Noch mehr verwirrt mich, dass *maßloser Sinn* gleichbedeutend mit dem englischen *disproportion* sein soll (dieses wird wiederum mit *die Disproportion* übersetzt).
Des weiteren finden sich unter *disproportion* jedoch noch das ungeliebte (Un)wort *das Missverhältnis* und das gewohnte und angemessene *die Unverhältnismäßigkeit*.
Was meinen Missmut / meinen Argwohn / meine negative Empfindung undefinierbarer Art weiter steigert.

---

Jetzt bin ich nach einer Sprachgefühlsachterbahn jedoch freudig gespannt, welche Antworten wohl darauf gewartet haben mögen, dass ich solch einen Hilfeschrei an euch richte:

Bitte klärt mich auf, ob es entweder eine sinnstiftende Bedeutung dieser für mich völlig unsinnigen Wortkombination gibt oder ob die Zeit doch nicht so sehr an meinem Geist genagt hat, wie ich des Öfteren glaube?

Comment: Der Eintrag _maßloser Sinn_ existiert nicht (mehr) unter dem angegebenen Link.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ich vermute, dass wir hier einen Fall von "Stille Post" haben.

Von den vier Google-Treffern für "maßloser Sinn" scheint Webster's Online Dictionary am verlässlichsten. Der [Link](http://www.websters-online-dictionary.org/translation/german/index364.html) führt aber auf eine Liste, die stark nach einer Sammlung von Stichwörtern aus einem Korpus aussieht - also lauter Phrasen, die willkürlich aus verschiedenen Kontexten herausgenommen wurden.

Wenn man die Liste überfliegt, fällt auf, dass teilweise sehr abseitige Begriffe enthalten sind, Umlaute verschieden geschrieben werden ("macht w**ue**tend" vs. "macht z**ä**h") und fehlerhafte Einträge auftauchen ("Machtübernahms" [sic!]).

Damit dann in so einer Liste eine solche Formulierung wie "maßloser Sinn" auftaucht, reicht schon eine einzige Textstelle weltweit, wo der Autor z.B. jemand sagen lässt: "Dein maßloser Sinn für Ordnung geht mir tierisch auf den Sack!" - möglicherweise gehört es dabei sogar zur Charakterisierung des Sprechers, dass er sich seltsam ausdrückt.

Meine Theorie: Jemand hat sich die Mühe gemacht, unbesehen eine Menge Einträge von Webster's in Leo zu übertragen und dabei auch Müll mitgenommen.

Comment: wow, ich würde gerne +3 geben :)

Comment: Lol, vielen Dank! :)

Comment: @Emanuel: Ich übernehme 1. Du eins. Fehlt noch eins.

Answer (score 4):

Ich denke hier ist die Übersetzung unvollständig oder einfach falsch. Die Phrase *maßloser Sinn* hat alleinstehend keine wirkliche Bedeutung. Selbst wenn man *Sinn* nach der [gehobenen Bedeutung aus dem Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Sinn#Bedeutung3a) als *Denken* interpretiert, ergibt die erwähnte Übersetzung aus Leo keinen Sinn.

Etwa die Beispielphrase aus dem Duden:

> das ist [nicht ganz] nach meinem Sinn
>
> this is [not quite] in my disproportion [?]

Auch Oxford kennt eine solche Bedeutung des englischen Worts nicht: [disproportion im Oxford dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disproportion?q=disproportion)

Eine bessere Verwendung ist etwa:

> X hat einen *maßlosen Sinn* für Y
>
> X has a disproportionate [=extreme] sense of Y

Wobei *maßlos* gewöhnlich als Synonym für *übermäßig* und *übertrieben* gilt, auch wenn das Wort wörtlich genommen nicht unbedingt so interpretiert werden muss.

Comment: Danke für deinen Beitrag. Doch ging es mir weniger um die Übersetzung an sich, sondern die Bedeutung im deutschen.

Answer (score 2):

Das Adjektiv *maßlos* beschreibt eigentlich, dass etwas über die Norm hinausgeht, wie in *maßlos übertrieben*. Die Frage ist nun, ob ein Sinn über die Norm hinausgehen kann. Zumindest können Synonyme zu *maßlos* das Wort *Sinn* enthalten, beispielsweise *irrsinnig*.

Sucht man im Internet nach *maßloser(oder maßlosen) Sinn* findet man keine relevanten Informationen. Es ist also schon mal nichts, was man üblicherweise sagen würde.

Ich habe noch mal die Definition sowie Synonyme von *[Sinn](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Sinn)* nachgeschlagen. Je nach Kontext kann man gegebenenfalls sagen, dass der *Sinn* übertrieben, folglich *maßlos* ist. Aber selbst bei keinem der vom Duden genannten Synonyme würde ich *maßlos* als Adjektiv tatsächlich verwenden.

Zwischenfazit: Es ist nicht falsch, aber auch nicht richtig.

Wie auch du, bin ich über die Übersetzung gestolpert. *Disproportion* bedeutet nach [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disproportion)

> lack of proportion, symmetry, or proper relation

Vielleicht kann man das unausgegliche Verhältnis zweier Dinge als *mehr als die Norm* und somit *maßlos* definieren, aber mir kommt es nicht in den Sinn, was das Wort *Sinn* hier zu suchen hat.

Die anderen Übersetzungen für *disproportion* finde ich hingegen akzeptabel.

Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, auf welcher Grundlage diese Übersetzung nach LEO gefunden hat, aber diese Übersetzung gilt wohl zu 99% als falsch. Den Kontext, wo das hinhaut, würde ich wirklich gerne sehen. Und angenommen, es gäbe diesen, bin ich mir sicher, dass es weitaus bessere Übersetzungen gibt.

Comment: Also ich hätte `irrsinnig` (Verdrehend der Tatsachen die zum Sinn führen würden) niemals als Synonym für `maßlos` gebraucht oder verstanden... Aber schonmal Danke für deine Bestätigung... Aber gib mir mal bitte einen Kontext in dem ein `Sinn` übertrieben wird / werden kann. Ich behaupte aus gefühl jetzt einfach, dass `Sinn` im Sinne von "Sinn machen" absolut ist... Kleiner Scherz am Rande: ich habe direkt bei LEO nach dem "edit"-Button und dem "flag"-Button gesucht.

Comment: Außerdem: wirklich pingelige Korrektur von dir :) Aber angesichts der Tatsache der mehrsprachigen Nutzer wird die Auslöschung meiner Stilmittel akzeptiert. ABER: Warum mussten auch die Anführungszeichen meines Ausrufs entfernt werden? Im Gegensatz zu deinen anderen Änderungen (Danke für die Mühe übrigens) kann ich das nicht nachvollziehen. Und meiner Meinung nach ist diese `Hervorhebung` deutlicher auf einem Bildschirm und damit angebrachter wie die _Kursivschrift_.

Comment: @MEB Du kannst jede Änderung rückgängig machen. Ich passe den Stil an das, wie es die meisten hier verwenden. Der Einheitlichkeit wegen. Die Stilmittel habe ich des Leseflusses wegen gelöscht. Aber nochmal: Wenn du mit meinen Änderungen nicht einverstanden bist, einfach rückgängig machen.

Comment: Auf *irrsinnig* bin ich nur des Dudens wegen gekommen, der diese in beiden Richtungen als Synonyme nennt. *Maßlose Übertreibung ist irrsinnig (oder auch wahnsinnig) übertrieben*.

Comment: Im Sinne von *Sinn machen* denke ich, kann der *Sinn* nicht *maßlos* sein. Aber es gibt noch andere Bedeutungen von *Sinn*: *Sie hat viel Sinn für Blumen.* Auch wenn ich es niemals so sagen würde, theoretisch - denke ich - ist es OK: *Dein Sinn nach Abenteuern ist maßlos (übertrieben).* Ich find das aber schon hart an der Grenze, und wie schon in meiner Antwort gesagt, ich erachte die Übersetzung als nicht so berauschend und würde gerne den Kontext lesen.

Comment: Danke. An soetwas hatte ich gestern garnicht gedacht... Die Änderungen bleiben wie sie sind. Ich frage nur gerne nach dem warum, um mein Tun bei guten Argumenten zu überdenken ;)

Comment: Ich weiß zwar nicht, wie Sinn *gemacht* wird, aber warum soll die Sinnproduktion nicht maßlos sein? Ich meine, auch bei der Produktion von Sinn sollte man wahrscheinlich maßvoll bleiben! ;-)

Comment: @celtschk Wir wissen, dass es im deutschen nur Sinn ergibt, aber das Englische beeinflusst uns doch jeden Tag. So it makes sense not being too picky with word choices made in comments.

Comment: Danke für die Korrektur, aber ich glaube mittlerweile das ich mir diesen Unsinn mit "Sinn machen" nicht mehr abgewöhnen kann ;)

Answer (score 2):

Die Fügung

> maßloser Sinn

ist wenig brauchbar in herkömmlichen, alltäglichen Kommunikationszusammenhängen. Jedoch kann ich mir durchaus vorstellen, in höhere Stilebenen, besonders in Versdichtung oder gehobener literarische Prosa, auf sie zu treffen.

> Orangener König, dein Reich schwindet hin,
>   Ein Opfer von Hybris und maßlosem Sinn.

Hier steht "maßloser Sinn" für die charakterliche Maßlosigkeit einer Person, für ihr Trachten nach Pomp und Prunk und ihre Neigung, vermeintliche eigene Leistungen ins unermessliche aufzublasen. Synonym wäre "Gesonnenheit nach Maßlosigkeit", aber "maßloser Sinn" ist dann natürlich schlanker ausgedrückt.

Comment: Ich gebe +1 für diesen kreativen Beitrag, auch wenn ich der Erklärung von @Mac zu 100 % zustimme. Übrigens existiert der Eintrag _maßloser Sinn_ gar nicht (mehr) unter dem in der Frage angegebenen Link.